# How to extract the bytes from a string variable in Python?

Tags: python

I need to extract the bytes from a string variable in Python (v 2.6) to pass it as a parameter for another function which expects a byte array.

Here is an example of what I have:

```
myStr = "some string"
```

What I need is something equivalent of a byte array but from the myStr variable.:

```
bytes = b'some string'
```

I tried using myStr.encode(), but I received a TypeError from the target function.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The version I am using is 2.6.

Comment: What encoding are you using to encode it? And what encoding does the function expect?

Comment: It looks like it is a duplicate from the one mentioned above. Good catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2 the `str` type is *already encoded*.

Could something like this serve you?

```
>>>import array
>>>s = array.array('b', myStr)
array('b', [115, 111, 109, 101, 32, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103])
```

Comment: I tried this approach and it worked.  All I needed was to create an array with the ASCII values.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

do you just need a list of the ascii values of the string?

```
 >>> map(ord, "some string")
 [115, 111, 109, 101, 32, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]
```